# Add numeric label to each box in grouped BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: labeling, charts

I would like to add a numeric label below each box in a grouped BoxWhiskerChart. I know how to do this in the ungrouped case, but cannot for the grouped case.

For example, the following generates four pairs of data blocks and plots these,

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[a, 1], 100], {a, {0, 3, 2, 5}}, {2}];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, None}, 
          ChartLabels -> {Placed[{1, 2, 3, 4}, Axis], None}]
```

which produces a plot like,

[image]

However let's say I want to add a specific number below each box. For example,

```
lNums = {5,10,15,4,7,8,1,3};
```

How can I do this in this case?

Note: I know I can do this manually but I was looking for a dynamic solution that will work when the data changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple possibilities:

```
data = Table[
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[a,1], 100],
    {a,{0,3,2,5}}, {2}
];
labels = Partition[{5,10,15,4,7,8,1,3}, 2];

BoxWhiskerChart[
    data,
    ChartStyle->{{Red,Green,Blue,Black},None},
    LabelingFunction->(Placed[Extract[labels,#2],Below]&),
    ChartLabels->{Placed[{1,2,3,4},Axis],None}
]

(* or *)

BoxWhiskerChart[
    MapIndexed[Labeled[#,Extract[labels,#2],Below]&, data,{2}],
    ChartStyle->{{Red,Green,Blue,Black},None},
    ChartLabels->{Placed[{1,2,3,4},Axis],None}
]
```

[image]

I didn't show both charts, as they look the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[a, 1], 100], {a, {0, 3, 2, 5}}, {2}];
lNums = {5, 10, 15, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3};
labels = Partition[lNums, 2];

labeleddata = Labeled[##, "LowerFence"]&@@@# & /@ (Transpose/@Transpose[{data, labels}]);
```

(You can also use `Below` in place of `"LowerFence"` above.)

```
BoxWhiskerChart[labeleddata, 
 ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, None}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{1, 2, 3, 4}, Axis], None}]
```

[image]